# How to give function to Button which is created programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create button programmatically and give a function to it.

Function: when I click on the button, remove/hide the button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO81d.png)

Comment: You can add an even Event handler to the `Button.Click` event. E.g `myButton.Click += ButtonClickHandler;`

Comment: Please, use google first. Show any sort of code you've done. Links are not acceptable. There are literally millions of examples for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your Function as an event:

```
protected void YourButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // To hide your button
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.visible = false;
    // Your code
}
```

Declare your button and attach the event to it

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Click += new EventHandler(YourButtonClickEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you dear. If I want to hide the button its self, what is the code?

Comment: Thank you , you helped me a lot :)